# Unity Jumpscare how to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Id like to add a jumpscare to my game but everything i find on the internet is with trigger of a box, i want to have one like the big horrror games. Im using unity engine. Ive tried to do it with a

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BFirstTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ThePlayer;
    public GameObject TextBox;
    public GameObject TheMarker;
    public AudioSource Line03;

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonAIO> ().enabled = false;
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayer());
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayer()
    {
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Looks like theres a weapon on that table";
        Line03.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
        TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
        ThePlayer.GetComponent<FirstPersonAIO> ().enabled = true;
        TheMarker.SetActive(true);

    }

}```
````

Comment: What is the issue? What doesn't work? What is the expected results compared to the one you have? What is the question?

Comment: hello everythings fine with the code, i need a explanation how i can do a jumpscare like the big ones

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly what this site is for. If you're requesting things like artwork to appear for a jumpscare, then there are other sites for this like reddit. StackOverflow is for receiving answers to specific question, not asking how to make a general concept.

That being said, there are various ways off the top of my head that you could make something like this.

- UI element that appears and disappears
- Character appears in front of you
- Loud noise plays along with animation

But from what I can see, you're particularly new to game development. That's okay! But from experience, it's better to take a step back and focus on a smaller project. I started last year and tried to make a big project but it didn't work out. Make something small and then start working your way up, learning and learning and learning! That's when it's going to be a lot easier to create large-scale games.

Anyways, good luck with your project and good luck with your game development learning!